# JLabel positioning into JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I have this code written to make a database connection and add a client:

```
//adding the left panel
JPanel left = new JPanel();
left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 500));
left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
add(left);

//adding the right panel
JPanel right = new JPanel();
right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 500));
right.setLayout(new BoxLayout(right, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
add(right);

//adding the jlabel title to the left panel
JLabel leftTitle = new JLabel("Add a client");
leftTitle.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
left.add(leftTitle);

//adding the jlabel title to the right panel
JLabel rightTitle = new JLabel("Make a reservation");
rightTitle.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
right.add(rightTitle);

//adding the jlabel "name"
JLabel nameL = new JLabel("Name:");
left.add(nameL);
```

and I want to move this JLabel here:
[image: move that "Name:" into the left]

I've tried doing `nameL.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);` but it's still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've used a `BoxLayout`.

```
left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Your `BoxLayout` is set to align things centered along the y-axis, so no amount of setting alignment is going to change that. In order to fix your problem, you need a different layout manager like `GroupLayout` or `CardLayout`.

Comment: i did it but it gives me an error : Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=Add a client,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER] is not attached to a horizontal group

Comment: You did not set your horizontal group. You need to tell every component where it sits vertically as well as horizontally.